# EF Core update table with dynamic name

Tags: c#, ef-core-6.0

I'm working on a database project where I need to update arbitrary records in any of the tables, but the table and column names are dynamic.

The messages I need to process are in the following format

```
        {
            "table": "Customers",
            "key_value": 123,
            "column_data": 
            {
                "Name": "John Smith",
                "Rate": 250
            }
        }
```

So in the table `Customers` I need to update the `Name` and `Rate` fields of the customer with `Id=123`

I tried the below solution where it seems I can pass dynamically the column but not the table name.
The line `context.Find(table, key);` doesn't compile.

```
public void UpdateRecord(string table, string column, int key, string value)
{
   var context = new MyDbContext();
   var entity = context.Find(table, key); // here I can't pass the table name
   context.Entry(entity).Property(column).CurrentValue = value;
   context.Entry(entity).Property(column).IsModified = true;
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: It is table name or class name? Which EF Core version? Do you need to update via change tracker only or via `ExecuteUpdate`?

Comment: I use EF 6.0 but I can change to 7.0 that I think has the `ExecuteUpdate`. My goal is to be flexible to accept any table and column name.

Comment: So it is Table Name and Column Name, not property name?

Comment: Columns are the property names  like `Id, Name, Rate` and tables are the class names like `Customer`.

Comment: IMO I would just execute raw sql in this case. No need to mess with EF.

Comment: I can write such function tomorrow, but you can try it by yourself. You have to define generic method `UpdateRecord<TEntity, TValue>(string column, int key, string value)`, find entity type in Model and dynamically invoke generic method.

Answer (score 0):

you can use System.Linq.Dynamic.Core and Add below Extensions

first you must add Class(Student) in MyContext
and you replace name Context( MyContext) with  your Context
and you need Extensions for get TableName
and  you need System.Linq.Dynamic.Core for dynamic Query

DbContext:MyContext class:Student

Method UpdateRecord:

```
 public class TestClass
    {
        public void UpdateRecord(string table, string tableClassNameSpace, string Column, int key, string value)
        {
     var tableName = table;
            //var tableClassNameSpace = "MyProject.Models.EntityModels";
            using (var dbContext = new MyContext())
            {
                var tableClassName = $"{tableClassNameSpace}.{tableName}";
                Type dynamicTableType = Type.GetType(tableClassName);    
                var dynamicTable = DBContextExtensions.Set(dbContext, dynamicTableType);      // DbSet
                var records = dynamicTable
                     .AsQueryable().Where("Id==@0  ", key)
                     .ToDynamicList()
                     .FirstOrDefault();
                PropertyInfo propertyInfo = records.GetType().GetProperty(Column);           
                propertyInfo.SetValue(records, value, null);
                dbContext.SaveChanges(); 
            }  } }
```

call Method

```
TestClass testClass = new TestClass();
testClass.UpdateRecord("Student", "ConsoleApp2", "Name", 2, "TestName2");
```

Package:1.System.Linq.Dynamic.Core 2.EF Core 6

Extensions Method

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;
public static class DBContextExtensions
{
   public static IQueryable<Object> Get(this MyContext _context, Type t)
   {
       return (IQueryable<Object>)_context.GetType().GetMethod($"get_{t.Name}").Invoke(_context, null);
   }
   // Or the modified set which handles ambigous ref issues:
   public static IQueryable<Object> Set(this MyContext _context, Type t)
   {
       return (IQueryable<Object>)_context.GetType().GetMethods()
               .First(x => x.Name == "Set" && x.ContainsGenericParameters)
               .MakeGenericMethod(t).Invoke(_context, null);
   }}
```

My Class Method

```
public class Student
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { set; get; }
   public string Name { set; get; }
}
```

MyContext

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
  public MyContext(){}     
  public DbSet<Student> Student => Set<Student>();
  protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
      => optionsBuilder
          .LogTo(Console.WriteLine, (_, level) => level == LogLevel.Information)         
  public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options)
  {  
  }
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
  }
}
```

Comment: You certainly like to put a lot of whitespace/blank lines in your answer to scroll through...

Comment: I removed a lot of space. No,I copied the code from Visual Studio